# jetpack compose exapmle No get method providing array access

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I copied a piece of code from the example in jetpack compose.[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Scaffold(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldState,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.material.FabPosition,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function1))

But in Android Studio a problem arises:
[image]

I wonder where is the problem? I'm still a beginner

The following is the complete code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme.colors
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Menu
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.freedom.android.ui.theme.MyApplicationTheme
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                Scaffold(
                    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                    drawerContent = { Text("Drawer content") },
                    topBar = {
                        TopAppBar(
                            title = { Text("Simple Scaffold Screen") },
                            navigationIcon = {
                                IconButton(
                                    onClick = {
                                        scope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.open() }
                                    }
                                ) {
                                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "Localized description")
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    },
                    floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End,
                    floatingActionButton = {
                        ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                            text = { Text("Inc") },
                            onClick = { /* fab click handler */ }
                        )
                    },
                    content = { innerPadding ->
                        LazyColumn(contentPadding = innerPadding) {
                            items(count = 100) {
                                Box(
                                    Modifier
                                        .fillMaxWidth()
                                        .height(50.dp)
                                        .background(colors[it % colors.size])
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MyApplicationTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

I think the problem is with the `colors` variable, it doesn't seem to be an array, but this was copied from the official documentation, I didn't change it.

```kotlin
package androidx.compose.material

object MaterialTheme {
    /**
     * Retrieves the current [Colors] at the call site's position in the hierarchy.
     *
     * @sample androidx.compose.material.samples.ThemeColorSample
     */
    val colors: Colors
        @Composable
        @ReadOnlyComposable
        get() = LocalColors.current
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [full source code of the sample the docs use](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/material/samples/ScaffoldSamples.kt;l=67), it has a top level object:

```
private val colors = listOf(
    Color(0xFFffd7d7.toInt()),
    Color(0xFFffe9d6.toInt()),
    Color(0xFFfffbd0.toInt()),
    Color(0xFFe3ffd9.toInt()),
    Color(0xFFd0fff8.toInt())
)
```

So yeah, the `colors` that sample is referring to *is* a list that you can index into. If you want to also have a semi-random set of colors for your backgrounds, you can copy that list into your code as well.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Could you please tell me how to find the complete sample code? There is so much in the documentation that I may have overlooked this information